# What is the purpose of extras in GcmPubSub.subscribe()?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe

The extras parameter of `void subscribe(String registrationToken, String topic, Bundle extras)` method of `GcmPubSub` class is usually set to `null`. [According the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmPubSub.html#subscribe(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)), it could contain *"additional information"*.

What additional information could be there? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact details of that additional information on the extras parameter, but what can I give you is an [example](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/logic/PubSubHelper.java) on how to use it. Also, you can check this link about the [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) that is generally used for passing data between various Android activities. It depends on you what type of values you want to pass, but bundles can hold all types of values and pass them to the new activity.

Comment: @KENdi In the linked file it is just passing argument, [which is set to null](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/2fec73aecf3d305e038b56c4edf2b71369f26796/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/ui/TopicsFragment.java#L170).